# How can we add a download attribute to all the <a> tags present inside <body></body> tag (using JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html

Using JavaScript, I want to add a 'download' attribute in all the `<a>` tags present on my webpage.

Current code is

```
<a href="link of some pdf file">View1</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file">View2</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file">View3</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file">View4</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file">View5</a>
```

What I want is to add download attribute in all the `<a>` tags at once using JavaScript.
The result should be same as shown below:

```
<a href="link of some pdf file" download>View1</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file" download>View2</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file" download>View3</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file" download>View4</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file" download>View5</a>
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: `[...document.getElementsByTagName('a')].forEach(link => link.setAttribute('download',''))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`document.querySelectorAll('a')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) can get all the `<a>` element in your document.

It returns an array so you can use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate through all the elements.

Finally, you can use [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to set an element's attribute.

You may see `<a download="">` but that's the same as `<a download>`.

See example below.

```js
var updateTextarea = function () {
  document.querySelector('textarea').value = document.querySelector('main').innerHTML;
};

var addDownload = function () {
  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(e) { e.setAttribute('download', ''); });
  updateTextarea();
};

updateTextarea();
```

```html
<main>
  <a href="link of some pdf file">View1</a>
  <a href="link of some pdf file">View2</a>
  <a href="link of some pdf file">View3</a>
  <a href="link of some pdf file">View4</a>
  <a href="link of some pdf file">View5</a>
</main>

<p><button onclick="addDownload()">Add download</button></p>

<p><textarea cols="50" rows="8" readonly></textarea></p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @josephting

Comment: @VaibhavDhasmana Don't forget to accept the best answer by clicking the tick icon next to the answer.

Comment: Done @josephting

Answer (score 0):

```js
var linkTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i= 0; i< linkTags.length; i++)
  linkTags[i].setAttribute('download','');
```

```html
<a href="link of some pdf file">View1</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file">View2</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file">View3</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file">View4</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file">View5</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the download attribute.

Your tags will look like this

```
<a href="link of some pdf file" download = "link_of_some_pdf_file.pdf">View1</a>
```

You should do this

```
element = document.getElementById(...);
element.setAttribute('download', element.getAttribute('href');
```

I'll let you figure out how to put it in a cycle ;)

Comment: But how to put it “in a cycle” is their exact question, you’ve answered what they already know.

Comment: @Lewis no, he wanted to do something like <a href ="" download> using Javascript, but that's not possible. So I answered to do <a href = "" download = ""> which is possible instead

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hrefs = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i=0, max=hrefs.length; i < max; i++) {
hrefs[i].setAttribute("download","pdf");
}
```

```html
<a href="link of some pdf file">View1</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file">View2</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file">View3</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file">View4</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file">View5</a>
```

the first thing is to get all the elements from the dom,

the traverse each a element and add attribute with setAttribute function

Answer (score 0):

You need to get All elements `a`, then loop through it set attribute of each element.

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i= 0; i< links.length; i++)
  links[i].setAttribute('download','');
```

```html
<a href="link of some pdf file">View1</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file">View2</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file">View3</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file">View4</a>
<a href="link of some pdf file">View5</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not really too much to this "`download`" attribute. You simply provide a **filename** as the *attribute value*. And then, when the user clicks on the `anchor link,` they will download the HREF location and save the resultant payload using the provided filename:

```
<a href="./generate-zip?id=4" download="assets.zip">Download</a>
```

In this case, the server-generated `ZIP file` will be saved to the user's computer as `"assets.zip".`

for further details you can visit

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3412-using-the-anchor-tag-href-and-download-attributes-to-force-a-file-download.htm

hope that would help you to sort out problem

Comment: This answers a completely different question. They know what the download attribute _is_, they want to know how to apply it via JavaScript.